# Delete content problem in Multilingual site with module Global redirect

Tags: 7

I have a multilingual mini site with 2 pages/nodes with 6 languages enabled. I don't have the translation for some language on some pages. I was hoping global redirect would help me with this by redirecting the user to the default language when the translation doesn't exist. This part only works partially but this is not not my concern for this thread.

At the beginning I added missing translations by putting the English version instead. When I learn the existence of the module Global Redirect I decided to delete those missing translation. I downloaded and activated Gloabl Redirect and started to delete the nodes which had a bad version. But when you do so, it does not delete the node of the language you selected, it deletes the default language node!!

So in other words if I have a node in English (default) and go to Content and select the delete link of the Spanish translation it will delete the English version and keep the Spanish version!! A by-product of this is to change the default language to the next on list...

Is it a know bug? What can I do to fix this other than NOT using Global Redirect? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If not already in use, I recommend using the [i18n module](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) instead of global redirect (which is imo more a SEO module) which let set you a fall back for not (yet) translated pages as well.
With this module you can also translate menu entries, path-settings, taxonomy terms etc. (even the site name and the site slogan (when using together with the variables module)).

Greetings krueschi

Comment: I have the i18n module activated. How do I active this functionality? (fallback for not yet translated pages)

Comment: When a page / article is not yet translated I set it to "language neutral" instead of language "English" or "German". So in my case - with only 2 languages for content installed - this works quite well. I've not tested it in case you have translations only some and not for all of your languages. So maybe you then need a "language neutral" one and an additional "translated" node for your source language too.